# Finding a volume using double integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

I am trying to find the volume of the region

$$\{ (x,y,z) \in (\mathbb R_0^+)^3 \mid y^2+z^2 \leq 9 \land y^2 \geq 3x \}$$

The answer is $\frac{27}{16} \pi$. The volume should be able to find using

$$V=\iint z \,\mathrm d A$$

Here you integrate the limits of $R$, where $R$ is the inferior base.

The graph for the functions would be something like this:

[image]

What I can not seem to do correctly is establish the limits for the integrals. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: *Exterior* to $y^2 = 3x$?  Doesn't that make the volume infinite?

Comment: It is, that why you are also told to limit it to the first octant.

Comment: Well, the exercise told me use double integrals, but any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the correct limits for the integrals. The solution is:
$$V=\int _0^3\int _0^{\frac{y^2}{3}}\sqrt{9-y^2}dxdy\:=\frac{27\pi }{16}$$